# WPF ImageProcessor slow first time use

Tags: c#, wpf, imageprocessor

In my WPF application i need to make thumbs from photo the user add to the program. To do this i use the ImageProcessor package which works perfect for me.
Bu i have one small problem the first use in an application session always takes 5 a 10 seconds to complete every next thumb making in the same session only takes milliseconds.

It looks like the DLL is only loaded on first use.
Is there a way to make this faster?

I've tried replacing ImageProcessor with ImageResizer and also tried loading ImageProccesor on application startup both didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the owner.
It appear to be the plugin search routine which was checking all referenced assemblies. My project uses many DevExpress components which gives me a few dozen assemblies in the project folder.

The owner has made exceptions in the search routine.
[Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/372)